# How to learn thread safe c# programming?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to know what is thread safe ? how to start to learn thread safe programmimg in c#? what is role of thread in web development ?

Comment: in fact I am new in programming . so please i request you all guys please guide me .

Comment: Fine you need to just follow the links and you will get what you wants

Comment: Still I am confuse in thread programming. how to find way ? please help me to learn threading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i would prefer you to read here: [Threading (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178)

Comment: ok I gone through this link. i need more practical way , by general objects understanding.

Comment: were you able to read it all including the examples in the Related Sections in just two minutes !?!?!?!??

Comment: @ Davide Piras: please refer me some links

Answer (score 4):

For .NET threading in general, I find the following link very useful: [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) by
Joseph Albahari.

For the last question, I would start with the following articles depending on which technology you are using:

- For web form: [Asynchronous Pages in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx) (a bit old but should still be relevant)
- For asp.net mvc: [Using an Asynchronous Controller in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx)

Also, the following article explains how ASP.NET uses threads when hosted on IIS 7.0 and IIS 6.0: [ASP.NET Thread Usage on IIS 7.0 and 6.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx).  The link is also a bit old but it covers up to .NET 3.5 sp1, so it could be a good start point as well.

Answer (score 3):

sure! take reference for startup : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740.aspx

Comment: Also you can take reference here : http://www.albahari.com/threading/ This is very simple way to learn threading

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more hands on approach than the MSDN reference I would suggest you read this free [ebook](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) .

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to programming I would recommend you read a bit about functional programming and side effects. Creating threads and using them is easy in C# but making them safe is difficult. I would recommend this article http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2008/09/12/side-effects-and-functional-programming/

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent programming is a vast an extremely complicated area. Rather than looking specifically at c# to begin with I would start by learning about the basics of concurrency. IE) What is locking? What is a Mutex, Latch, and Concurrent Queue, and why do we need to use them? IMO, a good place to start would be [this](http://swinbrain.ict.swin.edu.au/wiki/Concurrent_Programming) site created by Swinburne University in Australia.